# Entity Framework is not creating the database

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to create a code first database creation. I have 2 connection strings:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-1111\SERVER_2014; database=the_userdb;user=sa; password=myPassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="PmisDatabaseContext" connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-1111\SERVER_2014; database=the_database;user=sa; password=myPassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

At first, I was able to add a migration using this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public bool IsActivated { get; set; }
    public DateTime EnrollDate { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        //AspNetUsers -> User
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
            .ToTable("User");
        //AspNetRoles -> Role
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>()
            .ToTable("Role");
        //AspNetUserRoles -> UserRole
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>()
            .ToTable("UserRole");
        //AspNetUserClaims -> UserClaim
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>()
            .ToTable("UserClaim");
        //AspNetUserLogins -> UserLogin
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>()    
            .ToTable("UserLogin");
    }
}
```

then I 'enabled migrations' then 'add-migration InitialDatabase' then 'update-database' and was able to successfully created a new database with the tables for logging in.

Now I want to create a new database with a table named ImageLibraries so I did this in my model:

```
[Table("ImageLibrary")]
public class ImageLibrary
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
}
```

then added:

```
public class PmisDatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public PmisDatabaseContext()
        : base("name=PmisDatabaseContext")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<PmisDatabaseContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<PmisDatabaseContext>());
    }


    public virtual DbSet<ImageLibrary> ImageLibraries { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to 'add-migration AddedImageLibrary', in my migrations folder, I get the 'up()' and 'down()' without anything in it. It's not creating the new database and table. Can you please show me how to do this right. Thank you.

Comment: migrations don't create the database, they update one database state to the second. Simply access the database with a DbContext (with an actual call to the database) and the database will be created.

Comment: So I just create it the way I created it using the `public class PmisDatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public PmisDatabaseContext()
        : base("name=PmisDatabaseContext")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<PmisDatabaseContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<PmisDatabaseContext>());
    }


    public virtual DbSet<ImageLibrary> ImageLibraries { get; set; }
}` then just insert a record to it and it will be created?

Comment: obviously you'll need an instance of the context, not the class itself. but yes, in general you could say that. After model creation (right before the first EF db access) the initializer runs, that creates the database if it not exists in your case.

Comment: `using(var dbContext = new PmisDatabaseContext) { // insert statementst here... }`. Is this what you mean by `obviously you'll need an instance of the context, not the class itself..`?

Comment: yes, exactly. Of course you'll need to call the Constructor (new PmisDatabaseContext()) and the insert statements (if not pure sql) will have to be executed using SaveChanges(), but right before the EF db call the modelbuilder should run and afterwards your database will be created.